# Estimation of the magnitude of the second largest prime factor

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

Very special cases ignored, a large number is difficult to be completely factored if the second largest prime factor is large.

> Can we estimate the magnitude of the second largest prime factor of a random number $N$ , lets say , in the range $[10^{99},10^{100}]$ ?

For clarification : We assume that $N$ is not a power of a prime and only look at the distinct prime factors and choose the second largest of them.

I am only aware of an estimation of the number of distinct prime factors (roughly $\ln(\ln(N))$) , but this does not help to estimate how large the second largest prime factor will be in average.

Comment: What is the second largest prime factor of a prime?  If the largest prime factor is squared, does that count as the second largest prime?  So for $50=2\cdot 5^2$ is the second largest factor $2$ or $5$?

Comment: I don't think that is obvious.  It is not easy to tell a square, so if we are factoring $50$ we find $2$ easily, but finding the first $5$ is hard.  I would think you want the answer to $50$ to be $5$ and powers of primes be acceptable.

Comment: What I am actually looking for is something like : If a large number, lets say, near $10^{100}$ is not a power of a prime, how large is the probability that the second largest prime factor is at least $10^{20}$

Comment: it takes at least 5 prime factors before even 1 is below $10^{20}$ out of necessity.

Comment: okay possibly non distinctly. @RossMillikan test mod 24 and mod 36 I believe.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickman_function#Applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can estimate the number of numbers in $[10^{99},10^{100}]$ that have two prime factors greater than $10^{20}$ using the prime number theorem.  If we pick two numbers $a,b$ greater than $10^{20}$ the chance they are both prime is $\frac 1{\log a \log b}$  Letting $a \lt b$ we get the number of numbers with these two as prime factors is 
$$\int_{10^{20}}^{10^{49}}\int_{a}^{\frac{10^{100}}a}\frac {da\ db}{\log a \log b}=\int_{10^{20}}^{10^{49}}\operatorname{Li}\left(\frac{10^{100}}a\right)-\operatorname{Li}\left(a\right)da$$
[Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate&assumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22Integral%22,%20%22integrand%22%7D%20-%3E%22li(10%5E100%2Fx)-li(x)%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22Integral%22,%20%22rangestart%22%7D%20-%3E%2210%5E20%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22Integral%22,%20%22rangeend%22%7D%20-%3E%2210%5E49%22&assumption=%7B%22FVarOpt%22,%20%221%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%7B%7D,%20%7B%7B%7B%22Integral%22,%20%22variable%22%7D%7D%7D,%20%7B%7B%22Integral%22,%20%22rangestart%22%7D,%20%7B%22Integral%22,%20%22rangeend%22%7D%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22C%22,%20%22integrate%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Calculator%22,%20%22dflt%22%7D) gives an evaluation of $4.53287\cdot 10^{99}$ which seems amazingly high.  It would say $45\%$ of the numbers have two factors greater than $10^{20}$.  We have overcounted numbers with three or four factors greater than $10^{20}$.

Answer (score 0):

The random model for the primes says that when taking $n$ uniformly in $[1,x] $, for $p \le x^r$  we can consider that $n \bmod p$ is uniformly distributed and independent from one $p$ to the other.

Thus with $2ndLpf$ the second largest prime factor we'd have 
$$Pr[2ndLpf(n) = p]  \approx \frac1p\sum_{p<q <x}\frac1q\prod_{q<Q <x} (1-\frac1Q))\approx \sum_{p< q<x} \frac1{pq}\frac{\ln q}{\ln x}\sim \sum_{p<m <x} \frac1{pm \ln x}$$

$$\Bbb{E}[2ndLpf(n)] = \sum_{p \le x^r}p \ Pr(2ndLpf(n) = p)\approx  \sum_{p \le x}\sum_{p<m <x} \frac1{m \ln x}\\ \approx \sum_{k \le x}\frac{1}{\ln k}\sum_{k<m <x} \frac1{ m \ln x}\sim \sum_{k \le x} \frac{\ln x-\ln k}{\ln k \ln x}$$